# Missing Cities from Facebook all_cities_final.csv

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making Facebook App and I need to match the city from the user on Facebook with the city in my local database.
I've found the list of Cities from this link:
http://developers.facebook.com/attachme … _final.csv

But it seems that this is not the whole list, because there is no city from Macedonia in the list, but they do came up from auto complete when you try to write the city in your Hometown.

Am I missing something here, or is there some other list of Cities that I can find?

Also I've downloaded autocomplete_data.php from 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ads.getAutoCompleteData/
and it doesn't have all cities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I just have the same issue and figured the cities are now places in the graph

https://graph.facebook.com/114897945188014

[SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE page_id=114897945188014](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20page_id=114897945188014&access_token=2227470867%7C2.AQBjOMYngqwPNcp6.3600.1313967600.0-571421775%7CmsAwCCWAX_6RQhqbhdZ_SyNxQTY)